# Appending nested list values into a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a program that has a nested list which I wish to access and then append to a new list based on a condition. There are three *columns* in each list and I wish to know how to access them individually. Here's how it looks currently `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]`. An example to better explain this would be, if I wanted data from the second column my new list would then look like `['B', 'E', 'H']`.

This is what I have so far but I'm currently rather stuck..

```
n = 0
old_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]
new_list = []

for a, sublist in enumerate(old_list):
       for b, column in enumerate(sublist):
              print (a, b, old_list[a][b])
              if n == 0:
                     new_list.append(column[0])
              if n == 1:
                     new_list.append(column[1])
              if n == 2:
                     new_list.append(column[2])

print(new_list)
```

My current output..

```
0 0 A
0 1 B
0 2 C
1 0 D
1 1 E
1 2 F
2 0 G
2 1 H
2 2 I
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

My desired output ..

```
n = 0
new_list = ['A', 'D', 'G']

n = 1
new_list = ['B', 'E', 'H']

n = 2
new_list = ['C', 'F', 'I']
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]
>>> columns = list(zip(*L))
>>> columns
[('A', 'D', 'G'), ('B', 'E', 'H'), ('C', 'F', 'I')]
>>> columns[1] # 2nd column
('B', 'E', 'H')
```

Or if you want each column as a list to modify(since `zip` returns immutable tuples) then use:

```
columns = [list(col) for col in zip(*L)]
```

Comment: what does the `*` stands for ?

Comment: It unpacks the list into positional arguments, a good explanation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python

Comment: @StephaneRolland It's known as the "splat" and it unpacks `L` into args for `zip`

Comment: Thanks for your snappy response, I only wish to output one sublist though however. If n was 0, only ['A', 'D', 'G'] would be printed etc..

Comment: @user2298739 then just access the column at your desired index `columns[n]`

Comment: @jamylak maybe add a little note for him in your answer about `columns[n]`

Comment: @StephaneRolland Was just about to!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to this.. I'm getting the error `builtins.TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable`. Cheers for your patience.

Comment: @user2298739 Oh right no problem, you are using Python 3, where zip returns an iterator instead of a list, I'll update my answer, you just need `list(zip(*L))`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which does not use the `*` construction nor `zip()`:

```
for n in range(3):
    print('n = {}'.format(n))
    new_list = [sublist[n] for sublist in old_list]
    print('new_list = {}'.format(new_list))
```